# Error when enabling more warnings in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to enable more warnings and to treat warnings as errors in my project. I have put the following code in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_compile_definitions(hyper PRIVATE
                           $<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/W4 /WX>
                           $<$<NOT:$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>:-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror>
                           )
```

I get the following error on Linux using Clang 14.0.6 or GCC 12.1.1:

```
Cannot get compiler information:
    Compiler exited with error code 1: /usr/bin/c++ -xc++ -D-Wall -D-Werror -D-Wextra -D-Wpedantic -DFMT_LOCALE -DFMT_SHARED -DHL_DEBUG -DSPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL -DSPDLOG_SHARED_LIB -Dhyper_EXPORTS -g -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++20 -fpch-preprocess -v -dD -E
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/c++
    Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++,d --enable-bootstrap --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-cet=auto --enable-checking=release --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable-link-serialization=1 --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-multilib --enable-plugin --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-werror
    Thread model: posix
    Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
    gcc version 12.1.1 20220730 (GCC) 
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-D' '-Wall' '-D' '-Werror' '-D' '-Wextra' '-D' '-Wpedantic' '-D' 'FMT_LOCALE' '-D' 'FMT_SHARED' '-D' 'HL_DEBUG' '-D' 'SPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB' '-D' 'SPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL' '-D' 'SPDLOG_SHARED_LIB' '-D' 'hyper_EXPORTS' '-g' '-fPIC' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-std=gnu++20' '-fpch-preprocess' '-v' '-dD' '-E' '-D' '___CIDR_DEFINITIONS_END' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/cc1plus -E -quiet -v -D_GNU_SOURCE -D -Wall -D -Werror -D -Wextra -D -Wpedantic -D FMT_LOCALE -D FMT_SHARED -D HL_DEBUG -D SPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB -D SPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL -D SPDLOG_SHARED_LIB -D hyper_EXPORTS -D ___CIDR_DEFINITIONS_END /tmp/compiler-file9852660908641365533 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -std=gnu++20 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -fpch-preprocess -g -fworking-directory -dD -dumpbase compiler-file9852660908641365533
    ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/../../../../include/c++/12.1.1
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/../../../../include/c++/12.1.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/../../../../include/c++/12.1.1/backward
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/include
     /usr/local/include
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/include-fixed
     /usr/include
    End of search list.
    <command-line>: error: macro names must be identifiers
    <command-line>: error: macro names must be identifiers
    <command-line>: error: macro names must be identifiers
    <command-line>: error: macro names must be identifiers
    
    
    Compiler exited with error code 1: /usr/bin/c++ -xc++ -D-Wall -D-Werror -D-Wextra -D-Wpedantic -DFMT_LOCALE -DFMT_SHARED -DHL_DEBUG -DSPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL -DSPDLOG_SHARED_LIB -Dhyper_EXPORTS -I/home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/hyper/include -I/home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/hyper/src -I/home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/hyper/src/base -g -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++20 -Winvalid-pch -x c++-header -include /home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/cmake-build-debug/hyper/CMakeFiles/hyper.dir/cmake_pch.hxx -fpch-preprocess -v -dD -E
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/c++
    Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++,d --enable-bootstrap --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-cet=auto --enable-checking=release --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable-link-serialization=1 --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-multilib --enable-plugin --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-werror
    Thread model: posix
    Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
    gcc version 12.1.1 20220730 (GCC) 
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-D' '-Wall' '-D' '-Werror' '-D' '-Wextra' '-D' '-Wpedantic' '-D' 'FMT_LOCALE' '-D' 'FMT_SHARED' '-D' 'HL_DEBUG' '-D' 'SPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB' '-D' 'SPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL' '-D' 'SPDLOG_SHARED_LIB' '-D' 'hyper_EXPORTS' '-I' '/home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/hyper/include' '-I' '/home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/hyper/src' '-I' '/home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/hyper/src/base' '-g' '-fPIC' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-std=gnu++20' '-Winvalid-pch' '-include' '/home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/cmake-build-debug/hyper/CMakeFiles/hyper.dir/cmake_pch.hxx' '-fpch-preprocess' '-v' '-dD' '-E' '-D' '___CIDR_DEFINITIONS_END' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/cc1plus -E -quiet -v @/tmp/ccT7j88G -D_GNU_SOURCE -D -Wall -D -Werror -D -Wextra -D -Wpedantic -D FMT_LOCALE -D FMT_SHARED -D HL_DEBUG -D SPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB -D SPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL -D SPDLOG_SHARED_LIB -D hyper_EXPORTS -D ___CIDR_DEFINITIONS_END -include /home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/cmake-build-debug/hyper/CMakeFiles/hyper.dir/cmake_pch.hxx /tmp/compiler-file9852660908641365533 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -std=gnu++20 -Wall -Wextra -Winvalid-pch -fPIC -fpch-preprocess -g -fworking-directory -dD -dumpbase compiler-file9852660908641365533
    ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     /home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/hyper/include
     /home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/hyper/src
     /home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/hyper/src/base
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/../../../../include/c++/12.1.1
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/../../../../include/c++/12.1.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/../../../../include/c++/12.1.1/backward
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/include
     /usr/local/include
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/include-fixed
     /usr/include
    End of search list.
    <command-line>: error: macro names must be identifiers
    <command-line>: error: macro names must be identifiers
    <command-line>: error: macro names must be identifiers
    <command-line>: error: macro names must be identifiers
    
    
    Compiler exited with error code 1: /usr/bin/c++ -xc++ -D-Wall -D-Werror -D-Wextra -D-Wpedantic -DFMT_LOCALE -DFMT_SHARED -DHL_DEBUG -DSPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB -DSPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL -DSPDLOG_SHARED_LIB -Dhyper_EXPORTS -I/home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/hyper/include -I/home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/hyper/src -I/home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/hyper/src/base -g -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++20 -Winvalid-pch -include /home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/cmake-build-debug/hyper/CMakeFiles/hyper.dir/cmake_pch.hxx -fpch-preprocess -v -dD -E
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/c++
    Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++,d --enable-bootstrap --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-cet=auto --enable-checking=release --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-libstdcxx-backtrace --enable-link-serialization=1 --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-multilib --enable-plugin --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-werror
    Thread model: posix
    Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
    gcc version 12.1.1 20220730 (GCC) 
    COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-D' '-Wall' '-D' '-Werror' '-D' '-Wextra' '-D' '-Wpedantic' '-D' 'FMT_LOCALE' '-D' 'FMT_SHARED' '-D' 'HL_DEBUG' '-D' 'SPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB' '-D' 'SPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL' '-D' 'SPDLOG_SHARED_LIB' '-D' 'hyper_EXPORTS' '-I' '/home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/hyper/include' '-I' '/home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/hyper/src' '-I' '/home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/hyper/src/base' '-g' '-fPIC' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-std=gnu++20' '-Winvalid-pch' '-include' '/home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/cmake-build-debug/hyper/CMakeFiles/hyper.dir/cmake_pch.hxx' '-fpch-preprocess' '-v' '-dD' '-E' '-D' '___CIDR_DEFINITIONS_END' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/cc1plus -E -quiet -v @/tmp/ccfDgBhj -D_GNU_SOURCE -D -Wall -D -Werror -D -Wextra -D -Wpedantic -D FMT_LOCALE -D FMT_SHARED -D HL_DEBUG -D SPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB -D SPDLOG_FMT_EXTERNAL -D SPDLOG_SHARED_LIB -D hyper_EXPORTS -D ___CIDR_DEFINITIONS_END -include /home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/cmake-build-debug/hyper/CMakeFiles/hyper.dir/cmake_pch.hxx /tmp/compiler-file9852660908641365533 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -std=gnu++20 -Wall -Wextra -Winvalid-pch -fPIC -fpch-preprocess -g -fworking-directory -dD -dumpbase compiler-file9852660908641365533
    ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     /home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/hyper/include
     /home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/hyper/src
     /home/developer/projects/hyper_engine/hyper/src/base
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/../../../../include/c++/12.1.1
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/../../../../include/c++/12.1.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/../../../../include/c++/12.1.1/backward
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/include
     /usr/local/include
     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.1/include-fixed
     /usr/include
    End of search list.
    <command-line>: error: macro names must be identifiers
    <command-line>: error: macro names must be identifiers
    <command-line>: error: macro names must be identifiers
    <command-line>: error: macro names must be identifiers
    
    

[Failed to reload]
```

When I put the following code, I receive no errors (as far as I'm aware, this code does the exact same as the previous code, minus it's ability to be generated depending on the compiler being used):

```
target_compile_options(hyper PRIVATE
                       -Werror -Wall -Wextra
                       )
```

IIRC this used to work on previous projects of mine, so what gives?

Comment: You're adding macros in your non-working example.  That's why everything you added is prefixed with `-D` in the compilation command.

Comment: I've answered my own question based on your comment, if you'd like the rep, feel free to post an answer and I'll remove mine.

Comment: You should absolutely not hard-code `-Werror`.

Comment: @AlexReinking Considering that this is a personal project to better understand the language and the libraries I use, why shouldn't I address and possibly fix any warning that is given to me? `-Werror` simply helps me not miss warnings when building.

Comment: @MilanDierick - and then when you give your code to someone else and they use a different compiler, what do you think will happen? Bugs in warnings get fixed in minor versions. You might write code that compiles with, say, GCC 9.2 but then doesn't compile with 9.3. You should 100% write warning free code,  but _hardcoding_ Werror is a poor way to accomplish that

Comment: @AlexReinking I understand what you are saying. At the moment I develop using Clang, and I compile to a variety of targets using different compilers with CI, where the `-Werror` flag is not present. I didn't feel that including these specific details about my development environment would benefit my question, although I understand that it might portrait a poor programming habit to people that have just started programming. Do you want me to amend my question / answer? Or is that not done here on SO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stepthen Newell correctly pointed out in the comments, target_compile_definitions() adds compiler definitions, so replacing `target_compile_definitions()` with `target_compile_options()` does the trick, *derp*.